# Feature Reduction with Random Forest

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest

I am working with 46 variables ( remote sensing time series data - 8 days composite ) and around 466 samples, and using it to perform classification into 4 classes (1, 2, 3, 4). I want to reduce these features to most important 10-20

I was assuming that I would consider those features with highest **MeanDecreaseGini** and select **top 10** or **top 15** variables for further classification.
But going through some posts in this forum, it looks like this might not be a correct interpretation.

> **Could you help me with how to perform this reduction programetically?**

```
library(randomForest)
library(xlsx)
library(gdata)
setwd("E:/Working_Folder/R/Random_Forest/Test_Data")
all <- read.xls("Training_data_2015.xlsx", sheet = "NDVI_2015_all", perl="C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe")
```

## Create a sample index of the total data set and divide it to train and test set

```
sample_index <- sample(466,300)
rf_train <- all[sample_index,]
```

## When the class column is numeric, Convert the class column to factor so that the random forest performs classification rather than regression and  convert the training data into data frame

```
rf_train[,"Species"] <- factor(rf_train[,ncol(rf_train)])
rf_train <- as.data.frame(rf_train)
rf_test <- all[-sample_index,]
rf_model <- randomForest(Species~.,rf_train, importance=TRUE, ntree=500)
predict <- predict(rf_model,all)
all$predicted <- predict
```

## Check accuracey

```
table(all$Species,predict)
mean(all$Species==predict)
rf_model
importance(rf_model)
```

## The snippet of the output is as below:

[image]